# How to use multi valued parameter, if it was available in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Can we create multi valued parameters in tableau?

I want it to link to two diff data source as filter. I went through creating parameters but I struck at assigning that parameter to original column.

Comment: can you provide more context. screenshots, example code if possible.

Comment: A parameter can only have a single value. If you want to have a filter that applies to multiple data sources, you could try using a dashboard action filter or using data blending with a filter on a primary dimension.

Comment: when I am using action filter it is saying as missing fields in tabuleau @AlexBlakemore